# How to search for a specific word in a column of a table in sql server that contains XML data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `XMLInformation` with these columns: `ID`, `detailID`, `XML`, `RunDate` and `XMLDetail`.

The `XMLDetail` column contains the XML information. I wanted to search for a specific word from XML. Below is one of the XML. I wanted to make a query that will return all the row with XML that contains the word `GU` in the XML.

```
<InitialResponse transactionKey="0000000001025000000080001">
<AssesmentComplete>
<OutputAddress isStandardized="true" addressType="Current">
  <HybridAddress>
    <AddressLine>Street Address Address Line</AddressLine>
    <City>Gurgaon</City>
    <State>Haryana</State>
    <ZIP>122001</ZIP>
    <ZIP4>122002</ZIP4>
  </HybridAddress>
</OutputAddress>
<ID>36</ID>
<ID>43</ID>
<ID>44</ID>
<ID>45</ID>
<ID>47</ID>
<ID>49</ID>
<ID>75</ID>
<ID>GU</ID>
<ID>NH</ID>
<Score>0</Score>
<MatchAssesment>0</MatchAssesment>
<FraudIndicator />
<AtomicScores />
```

Comment: Does that word/fragment have to be in a specific location in the XML, or just anywhere in the XML at all? Does it have to be a **value** of an XML node, or could it even be the name of the XML node itself?

Comment: The word needs to be under the <ID> tag. It needs to be a value of the XML Note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM XMLInformation WHERE CAST(XMLdetail.query('//.="GU"')  AS VARCHAR) ='true'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
;WITH XmlIds AS
(
    SELECT 
        xi.ID, xi.DetailID, xi.RunDate,
        IDValue = XCol.value('.', 'varchaR(50)')
    FROM 
        dbo.XMLInformation xi
    CROSS APPLY
        XMLDetail.nodes('/InitialResponse/AssesmentComplete/ID') AS XTbl(XCol)
)
SELECT *
FROM XmlIds
WHERE IDValue = 'GU'
```

Basically, the CTE takes all `<ID>` values from the XML content and matches them to the other columns in the base table, and then you can select from this list of `IDValue` those that you need

Side note: the correct spelling would be **assessment** (twice with **two** `s` letters).

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for your performance to use [exist() Method (xml Data Type)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx)

```
select *
from XMLInformation
where XMLDetail.exist('//*[text() ="GU"]') = 1
```